# How to detect and crop character from an image having some bounding lines in python?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm having an image and i want to crop only the number inside with out the lines bounding around image. Here is the sample image:

[image]

As you can see there is 2 lines on the right and bottom of the image, i want to crop only number `8`, if nothing inside, i will return `None` for the result, but with my code, it also return the area which include these line. So is there anyway to fix this?

Result i got:

[image]

Or with empty image, i got:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import cv2

def process(image, readFile=True, returnType='binary'):
    out_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Performing OTSU threshold
    ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(out_gray, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    
    # Specify structure shape and kernel size. 
    # Kernel size increases or decreases the area 
    # of the rectangle to be detected.
    # A smaller value like (10, 10) will detect 
    # each word instead of a sentence.
    rect_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (8,8))
    
    # Appplying dilation on the threshold image
    dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh1, rect_kernel, iterations = 1)
    # Finding contours
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    if len(contours) <= 0:
        return False
    
    contours, boundingBoxes = sort_contours(contours, 'left-to-right')
    
    # Creating a copy of image
    im2 = img.copy()
    idata = 0
    # Looping through the identified contours
    # Then rectangular part is cropped and passed on
    # to pytesseract for extracting text from it
    # Extracted text is then written into the text file
    i = 1
    minHeight = 10
    minWidth = 10
    result = []
    for cnt in contours:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

        # Drawing a rectangle on copied image
        rect = cv2.rectangle(im2, (x, (y-1)), (x + w, y + h + 1), (0, 255, 0), 1)
        cv2.imwrite(f'{constant.__RESULT_PATH}/cutted123withbounding.png', im2)
        # Cropping the text block for giving input to OCR
        cropped = im2[y:y + h, x:x + w]

        if w >= minWidth and h >= minHeight:
            result.append(thresh1)
        i = i + 1
    return result
```

Comment: You can filter your contours on the basis of a couple of things - size (width/height), centroid, contourArea, extent, solidity. Check this link out and apply the properties that apply in your case to narrow down to your use case. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will check the docs to make sense :)